# Calculating interest rate in java

Tags: java, for-loop, rate

I'm making a method that are supposed to calculate the interest rate of an amount over a certain period of years (these values are already defined in the parameters).
This is the code i have so far:

```
    public void balance(int amount, double rate, int year){
    double yearlyRate = amount * rate;
    double totalAmount;


    System.out.print(amount + " :- " + " grows with the interest rate of " + rate);

    for (int i = 0; i <= year; i++ ){

          for ( int j = amount; j)
              totalAmount = amount + yearlyRate;
              System.out.println(i + "   " + totalAmount);
    }

}
```

I was on my way to make the nested for-loop as you can see there where there is missing code. Here i ran in too some trouble. The first for-loop runs through the years and the other are supposed to calculate the total amount. To be clear the years that are defined in the variable "int year" let's say that it is 7, then the program are supposed to calculate the growth of the amount each year so:

```
year1 totalAmount 
year2 totalAmount 
year3 totalAmount 
and so on.....
```

The main method looks like this:

```
public void exerciceG(Prog1 prog1) {
    System.out.println("TEST OF: balance");
    prog1.balance(1000, 0.04, 7);
}
```

I appreciate any help i can get!

Comment: What sort of "trouble" did you run into? Is there an error in your code? Is the calculation incorrect?

Comment: @wahwahwah i don't know how to get the second loop to calculate the growth of the totalAmount for each year.

Comment: The `rate` is an input to the method, so you aren't "calculating the interest rate of an amount". Are you trying to find how much in total has been paid? Also, the inner `for` isn't constructed properly to accomplish anything. What do you want it to accomplish? What should the output look like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one change to make, but there may be a lot else to do as I mentioned in comment:

```
totalAmount = totalAmount + amount + yearlyRate;
```

which could be written:

```
totalAmount += amount + yearlyRate;
```

You also might want to drop the `for j` loop since it doesn't do anything as is.

***EDIT***

This is a guess since I'm not sure we know what the objective is, but how about:

```
public static void balance(int amount, double rate, int year){

  double yearlyInterestPaid ;
  double totalAmount = amount;


  System.out.println(amount + " :- " + " grows with the interest rate of " + rate);

  for (int i = 0; i <= year; i++ ){

    yearlyInterestPaid = totalAmount * rate;
    totalAmount += yearlyInterestPaid;
    System.out.println(i + "   " + totalAmount);
  }
}
```

This is the output:

```
TEST OF: balance
1000 :-  grows with the interest rate of 0.04
0   1040.0
1   1081.6
2   1124.8639999999998
3   1169.85856
4   1216.6529024
5   1265.319018496
6   1315.93177923584
7   1368.5690504052736
```

It's reasonable to assume that this is the objective.

Comment: This helped i think i know how i can make thw whole program work now, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think the answer you are looking for is this

```
     for (int i = 0; i <= year; i++ ){
            amount = amount + yearlyRate;
             System.out.println(i + "   " + amount);                     
        }
```